# How do I avoid repeated code in this section?

Tags: python

`ds_trn, ds_val = SetDataset(trn, batch_size, 'train'), SetDataset(val, batch_size, 'val')`

How do I avoid two appearances of SetDataset, and make it just one?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it would be less readable, to my mind:

```
ds_trn, ds_val = (SetDataset(thing, batch_size, name) for thing, name in [(trn, 'train'), (val, 'val')])
```

This looks like overkill for two variables, but it'll really shine if you need a relatively big list of `SetDataset` objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably useful only if you have much more than two objects to initialize:

```
ds_trn, ds_val = map(lambda p : SetDataset(*p), [(trn, batch_size, 'train'), (val, batch_size, 'val')])
```